# Is it not necessary to implement get method in class B ? Why compiler not enforcing ? Any concepts I missed?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, overriding

```
interface A{
    public void get();

    public void set();
}

abstract class abstractA implements A{
    @Override
    public void get(){
        System.out.println("in get funciton");
    }

    abstract public void set();
}


class B extends abstractA implements A{
    @Override
    public void set(){
        System.out.println("In set method");
    }
}
```

Is it not necessary to implement get method in class B?

Is it because abstractA already implemented the same method ?

Is this multiple inheritance ?

Comment: An abstract class is a class with one or more abstract methods. Subclasses must either define the abstract methods, or be abstract themselves. Abstract classes can have non-abstract methods, which don't need to be implemented. This has nothing to do with multiple inheritance, which is not supported in java.

Comment: Why do you think `B` would need to define `get()`?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it not necessary to implement get method in class B?

No, since `abstractA` already implements it and `B` extends `abstractA`.

> Is it because abstractA already implemented the same method ?

Yes. And because `B` extends `abstractA`. Both are required for this to work.

> Is this multiple inheritance ?

No, it is not. `B` is still inheriting only one class - `abstractA`.

Comment: The contrary of multiple inheritance is not extending only one class, it's having a linear inheritance tree

Comment: The important word is "still". As long as you aren't Object, you are always extending exactly one class...

Comment: If `B extends A` and `C extends B` then `C` inherit members from both `A` and `B`, thus inheriting from several classes, but linearily

Comment: ...while still extending exactly one class. But I agree, not perfectly worded.

Comment: You said inherit, not extend

Answer (score 1):

No because get() is already implemented in abstractA. This is inheritance.

Java does not allow multiple inheritance (which consist in inheriting from multiple classes BTW). The class B inherits from abstractA, and implements the behavior required by A. Actually, you could write your code like this :

```
interface A{
    public void get();
    public void set();
}

abstract class abstractA implements A{
    @Override
    public void get(){
        System.out.println("in get funciton");
    }

    abstract public void set();
}


class B extends abstractA /* no need to specify that B implements A */{
    @Override
    public void set(){
        System.out.println("In set method");
    }
}
```

B inherits everything implemented by abstractA, which also include its interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

B inherits the implementation of `get()` from abstractA.

Multiple inheritance is when B inherits from more than one classes. Which is not the case here.

Comment: It would be multiple inheritance _if_ B extended more than one class, but the Java language does not allow you to do that.

Comment: However, Java 8 allows concrete methods on interfaces, which is kind of a restricted multiple inheritance